pydantic_settings library is not known by the python after the python file tracked by the git
I am trying to use pydantic_settings in my config.py file and it is okay until file is tracked by the git, which raise up an error called "No module named pydantic_settings"
To become certain about the problem root, I use  git rm --cached config.py to untrack the config.py and then pydantic_settings is become validate . So from that result, I make sure that the problem is taken place when the file is tracked by the git
Is there anyone who could help me?

Where exactly are you getting that error? git does not analyze your code in any way.

In my IDE(VScode), I don't know why....but I assume the cause of the problem is file being tracked by the git, because when I untracked  the file, python recognize the pydantic_settings
